# How to create a leaderboard ranking in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a list of data, i need to display their ranking based on their score, getting the top 1-3 or top 10 is easy, but can i get their ranking based on their position in the row? i am trying to get the first two and last two if you are in the middle of the row for example.

Users table

```
ID| User_id|Score|
1     1142    12
2     53      55
3     12      44
4     66      33
5     77      22
6     123     11
7     321     11
8     456     88
9     654     66
10    896     44
11    536     24
12    990     11
```

So for example the `user_id: 123` will login, i should be able to retrieve the data

```
ID| User_id|Score|
4     66      33
5     77      22
6     123     11
7     321     11
8     456     88
```

i am trying to display this in my view,

like this. so this will be the output in the view.

```
RANK 21:  1142
RANK 22:   77
RANK 23: 123
RANK 24:  N/A
RANK 25:  N/A
```

and if there is no below or above him it should be N/A the idea is the user who is login should always be in the middle.

how can i get the first two and last two? is this possible in MYSQL? and if there is no below or above him what should i do. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: 'and if there is no below or above him what should i do' - You are going to have to tell us what should happen. And what does the desired output have to do with ranking?

Comment: hi sir , i edited my question, sorry.

Comment: Consider handling the ranking in your php loop

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like the following:

```
select * from  users where User_id=123
union all (
  select * from users 
  where User_id <  123
   limit 2
) 
union all (
  select * from users 
  where User_id > 123 limit 2
) 
order by User_id
```

Comment: it is still did not work sir. i am not getting the accurate rows for it, i am only getting four rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,user_id,score
FROM users
WHERE user_id =123 OR user_id BETWEEN (LAG(LAG(user_id=123)) AND LEAD(LEAD(user_id=123)))
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: ```#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND LEAD(LEAD(user_id))) END) AS user_id
FROM users
WHERE user_id =123``` i am having these error sir

Comment: @Janessa Bautista mariadb is not mysql you should tag the question mariadb and check that your version supports window functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the relative rank for 123 is 0 and the relative ranks for the other rows we are interested in is -2,-1,1,2. Once we have this and the actual rank for 123 then actual rankings for the other rows is simple to calculate.

```
select t.rnk + relativerank as finalrank,
         coalesce(dummy,'n/a') finaluserid  

from
(
select 0 as relativerank,t.*, 123 as dummy from t where user_id = 123
union all
select -1 ,t.*,(select user_id from t t1 where t1.Score > t.score order by t1.score asc  limit 0,1) plus1  from t where user_id = 123
union all
select -2, t.*,(select user_id from t t1 where t1.Score > t.score order by t1.score asc  limit 1,1) plus2  from t where user_id = 123
union all
select 1, t.*,(select user_id from t t1 where t1.Score < t.score order by t1.score desc limit 0,1) minus1 from t where user_id = 123
union all
select 2, t.*,(select user_id from t t1 where t1.Score < t.score order by t1.score desc limit 1,1) minus2 from t where user_id = 123
) s
left join
(select  t.*, 
            if(score <> @p,@rnk:=@rnk+1,@rnk:=@rnk) rnk,
            @p:=score p
from t
cross join (select @rnk:=0,@p:=0) r
order by score desc
) t
on t.user_id = s.user_id
order by finalrank ;

+-----------+-------------+
| finalrank | finaluserid |
+-----------+-------------+
|         7 | 77          |
|         8 | 1142        |
|         9 | 123         |
|        10 | n/a         |
|        11 | n/a         |
+-----------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```